# Function that enables fields based on checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple code that just has to check if a checkbox is checked and if so enable some fields that, by default, should be disabled.

I have written the next code which I know can be severely improved. Could anyone tell me how? I tried getting the siblings of the checkbox also but that just caused some trouble.

```
$(function(){    
$('#amount').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#period').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#key').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#api').change(function(){
                if($('#apiEnabled').is(':checked')){
                    $('#amount').attr('disabled','');
                    $('#period').attr('disabled','');
                    $('#key').attr('disabled','');
                }else{
                    $('#amount').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#period').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#key').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer accurately without seeing your markup, but maybe you can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to alleviate code redundancy. You can also use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to enable or disable your elements more easily:

```
$(function() {
    var $elements = $("#amount, #period, #key");
    $elements.prop("disabled", true);
    $("#api").change(function() {
        $elements.prop("disabled", !$("#apiEnabled").is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){    
    var $els = $('#amount, #period, #key');
    $('#api').change(function(){
        var unchecked = !this.checked;
        $els.each(function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled', unchecked);
        });
    });
});
```

And if applicable change:

```
var $els = $('#amount, #period, #key');
```

To:

```
var $els = $('#api').siblings();
```

## Example Here:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/BpVkw/

Answer (score 0):

This is my take at it, but if you won't be needing the separate elements all over the place, then take @Frédéric Hamidi's advice and create a single object.

```
$(function(){
    var $amount     = $('#amount'),     // cache jQuery objects
        $period     = $('#period'),     // to avoid overhad
        $key        = $('#key'),        // of fetching them
        $apiEnabled = $('#apiEnabled'); // all the time
    $amount.prop('disabled', true);
    $period.prop('disabled', true);
    $key.attr('disabled', true);
    $('#api').change(function(){
        if ($apiEnabled.is(':checked')) {
            $amount.prop('disabled', false);
            $period.prop('disabled', false);
            $key.prop('disabled', false);
        } else{
            $amount.prop('disabled', true);
            $period.prop('disabled', true);
            $key.attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache your set of elements to prevent jQuery from looking them up every time you refer to them. You can also group them all into one set because you are applying the same code to all three of them.

`prop` can be used instead of `attr` which is new in jQuery 1.6+. `prop` is better suited to checkboxes and setting things as `disabled`.

Now that all three elements are grouped, you have one place (the `checkboxes` variable) that you can add or remove new checkboxes. It also means more succinct code in your `change` event.

```
$(function(){

    // Cache the elements
    var checkboxes = $("#amount, #period, #key");

    // Disable them using prop rather than attr (jquery 1.6+)
    checkboxes.prop('disabled', true);

    $("#api").change(function(){

        if($('#apiEnabled').is(':checked')) checkboxes.prop('disabled', false);
        else checkboxes.prop('disabled', true);

    });

});
```